# Can I pass variable controller function to a function link in a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using a custom directive on angularjs, and I want to pass some variables to the directive in order to build the directive with the data seted, the data is obtained from a $http response but this takes to long and nothing hapens when the variables are populated with the data response.

What I think is if I can make the request in the controller function inside the directive maybe I can set a $timeout function until the response conclude, but the questions is that if I get the data in a $http reponse and fill up the variable with this data I can pass it to the link function?

**EDIT:** The finally result is a set o fields in a form, filling it in a dynamic way from a json object.

Comment: to pass anything to a directive you can use a service. also, you can use promises to wait for data from your HTTP request. In addition, it all is just hand-waving if you do not have specific code to discuss.

Comment: better specify what you want to build in directive to seek for a proper answer

Comment: @DanielA.White Yup, but I'm in a isolate scope, and when I tried to debug the variables defined in the scope I just see the ones that I defined in the directive scope.

Comment: @akonsu any reference that I can use to do that, please.

Comment: @RubénGalvan well, here is a documentation page for services: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services, and here is one for promises: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: @elaijuh I just edited to specifies a little bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically if you have some information you want to share with a custom directive **you do this via the attributes manually, or using [isolate scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-).**

Imagine I had a custom directive to display some details about a `widget` but I wanted it to be generic... then I could write my directive like this:

```
{
   restrict: 'E',
   template: '<div>{{widget.name}}</div>',
   scope: {
      widget:'=' //Allows two way binding with parent scope
   }
}
```

**This is the simplest possible use case, but this will allow me to bind to that object within my directive and have it be totally isolated.**

Assuming I have a controller that actually looks up my widget from an `$http' call, I could the directive like so:

```
<!-- 
    widget attribute is made available because of how we
    declared our directive definition.
-->
<widget-directive widget="ctrl.myWidget"></widget-directive>
```

If your directive is more advanced, and you need to perform some actions based on changes to that object, then you can simply watch it in your [link function](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-link-):

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
   scope.$watch('widget', function(newVal, oldVal){
      // 
      //Do something here now that 'widget' has changed
      //
   });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Josh, but in someway the request it takes to long and when I set a variable(js object) to be watched aparently is not working :(

Comment: @RubénGalvan - Any more specifics on this? I can write a working code snippet that would demonstrate how this works. The amount of time it takes to retrieve the data shouldn't matter.

Comment: Yes, well basically I got a json string from a wcf services, and i put a watcher on the variable that is populated with the request but when this happen the function link in my directives already was fired and the watcher do not refresh when the variable is populated with the info request, I do not if I´m clear with this, but thanks in advance @Josh

Answer (score 0):

When you have to watch an object (deep watch), you can declare your watch like this:

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
   scope.$watch(function () { return scope.widget; }, function(newVal, oldVal){
      scope.widget = newVal;
   }, true);
}
```

Note the function returning the object, and the true added to the end of the watch.